# Chartjs annotation plugin to add vertical line not working

Tags: plugins, annotations, chart.js

I'm trying to add a vertical line in a two line graph using chart.js. I've even to the demo code from their page but not even that is working. It seems like I'm missing something by I have reviewed the code N times and couldn't figure it out what.
I've tried several examples but none worked for me.
Could someone help me figure it out why it doesn't work for me?

[image: working graph but missing vertial line]

Here's the data

```
[
{"date":1,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":1750},{"date":2,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":1795.06},{"date":3,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":1916.97},{"date":4,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":1997.31},{"date":5,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":2187.67},{"date":6,"cumulativePresentMonth":2061.61,"cumulativePastMonth":2325.18},{"date":7,"cumulativePresentMonth":2161.2,"cumulativePastMonth":2334.73},{"date":8,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2388.39},{"date":9,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2406.26},{"date":10,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2661.98},{"date":11,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2661.98},{"date":12,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2661.98},{"date":13,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2661.98},{"date":14,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2711.35},{"date":15,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":16,"cumulativePresentMonth":2300.21,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":17,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":18,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":19,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":20,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":21,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":22,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":23,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":24,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":25,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":26,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":27,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":28,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5},{"date":29,"cumulativePresentMonth":null,"cumulativePastMonth":2766.5}
]
```

Here's the annotation setup

```
const annotation1 = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleID: 'x',
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'black',
  value: 15,
  label: {
    content: 'restock',
    display: true
  },
};
```

And here's the graph setup and config

```
            const data = {
              datasets: [
                {
                  // type: 'line',
                  label: 'Past month',
                  data: spentData,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: 'red',
                  borderDash: [5,5],
                  pointStyle: false,
                  parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'date',
                    yAxisKey: 'cumulativePastMonth'
                  },
                }
                ,
                {
                  // type: 'line',
                  label: 'Current month',
                  data: spentData,
                  // borderWidth: 3,
                  pointStyle: false,
                  borderColor: 'green',
                  parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'date',
                    yAxisKey: 'cumulativePresentMonth'
                    // ,
                    // 
                  },
                }
              ]
            };

const scalesLables = {
          x: {
            display: true,
          },

          y: {
            display: true,
          },
        };


const annotation1 = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleID: 'x',
  borderWidth: 3,
  borderColor: 'black',
  value: 15,
  label: {
    content: 'restock',
    display: true
  },
};


const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: 'date',
        },
       scales: scalesLables, //scales
        plugins: {
          annotation: {
            annotations: {
              annotation1
            }
          }
        } ,// plugins
    } // options

};

  const dailyChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('chartCompare'),
      config
  );
```

Comment: It seems OK to me, [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvk9tp6f/). I only had to change the `type` of the x axis to `"linear"`, since with the default `"category"` I didn't get the lines either, since it had everything compressed to one point on x.

Comment: I see the jsfiddle works great. But still not working for me. The only thing that changed it was the scale. Instead showing all dates, it show by 5s, as the jsFiddle. This is so frustrating :( What am I missing??

Comment: In the version I have, if you want to keep x as `"category"` axis, you'd have to make `date` string, see this [fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/fqg8921r/)

Comment: I have figure it out. I feel so dumb. I never added the reference to the "chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js" library. I really thought that it would be part of the chart.js library. I added the reference and all works fine. Thanks a lot and sorry for the lack of knowledge. Thanks guys